# whmcs hook ClientLogin not running

Tags: php, client, whmcs

I'm trying to create a simple code to hook for when the client logs on, using [ClientLogin](http://docs.whmcs.com/Hooks:ClientLogin) but it does not run, did the same thing to hook `ClientLogout` and works perfectly. Any help?

```
<?php

      function email_teste(){
        echo "<script> console.log('simple function'); </script>";
      }





    add_hook("ClientLogin",1,"email_teste");

?>
```

Comment: (I presume `ClienteLogout` was just a spelling/translation error? The docs indicate it is `ClientLogout`).

Comment: Couple of things to check: are you sure your hook setup code is being called? At what point are events called? If the page has not rendered at all when the hook is triggered, you will be rendering `<script>` tags before the doctype, and if they are called at the end, you'll be rendering the tag after the closing HTML tag (and both may be prone to failure). Maybe this event is indeed being triggered and you just can't see it - consider logging to a temporary file to test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are not seeing anything is most likely because WHMCS redirects the user so quickly that you never see the output.

To prevent the redirect you could do this.

```
function email_teste(){
    echo "<script> console.log('simple function'); </script>";
    die();
}
```